# Kotlin: Can I overwrite a function with another function? (like override)

Tags: kotlin

I'm a Kotlin beginner.
I am not sure if the way I try is correct.
Now I want to override and **capturing variables**.

Suppose this is a method of `SOMETHING` class that can be overridden:

```
fun whoAreYou() {}
```

And this is my function:

```
fun thisFuntionsIs(): ()->Unit {
    var i = 0
    println("It's parent Function!")
    return { println("It's child Function! ${i++}") }
}
```

Now I tried to override the existing function with the new one:

```
fun whoAreYou() = thisFuntionsIs() // Suppose used the override keyword
```

Now when I run this function it prints out a "parent" message every time.

This is not what I wanted.☹

If `whoAreYou` was a property, not a method, it would have been worked I wanted.

```
class SOMETHING {
    var whoAreYou = ()->{} // If it was a property...
    // fun whoAreYou() {} // But the current situation is
}
SOMETHING.whoAreYou = thisFuntionsIs()
SOMETHING.whoAreYou() // Yea~ I wanted that
```

Is there a solution? Or am I totally wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to override, you need to make your parent class and function `open`, then override the function in an extended class:

```
open class Parent {
    protected var counter = 0;
    open fun whoAreYou() = "It's parent Function!"
}

class Child : Parent() {
    override fun whoAreYou() = "It's child Function! ${counter++}"
}

fun main() {
    val parent: Parent = Parent()
    val child: Parent = Child()

    println(parent.whoAreYou()) // It's parent Function!
    println(child.whoAreYou()) // It's child Function! 0
    println(child.whoAreYou()) // It's child Function! 1
    println(child.whoAreYou()) // It's child Function! 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works. Maybe you just misinterpret results. Slightly modified version:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = SOMETHING()
    x.whoAreYou = thisFuntionsIs()
    x.whoAreYou()
    x.whoAreYou()
}

class SOMETHING {
    var whoAreYou = fun() {
        System.out.println("It's parent Function!")
    }
}

fun thisFuntionsIs(): () -> Unit {
    var i = 0
    System.out.println("It's Function!")
    return { System.out.println("It's lambda! ${i++}") }
}
```

Output:

```
>  It's Function!
>  It's lambda! 0
>  It's lambda! 1
```

The line `x.whoAreYou = thisFuntionsIs()` means that `thisFuntionsIs` is called and `x.whoAreYou` is assigned to anonymous function return by `thisFuntionsIs`.